# How does dynamically allocating a struct in C work?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, malloc

I recently had an assignment where I had to dynamically allocate memory for a struct. I used this method:

```
myStruct *struct1 = malloc(sizeof *struct1);
```

This worked just fine. However, I don't understand how. I would think that the `struct1` pointer is uninitialized at that point and should therefore have a size of nothing. So therefore how does `malloc(sizeof *struct1)` return a valid amount of memory to allocate?

Comment: Keep in mind that sizeof gets resolved at compile time, not at runtime

Comment: @PeteBaughman: Except in the case of variable length arrays of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof` operator in C doesn't evaluate the operand.  It just looks at the type.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof i++);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run the above program, you will see that `i` is still 0.

So, in your example, `*struct1` is not evaluated, it's only used for type information.

Comment: so basically it looks at all the data types in the struct and allocates memory accordingly?

Comment: I've never tried to do that, but only by coincidence.  Thx, nice, concise answer too.

Comment: A word of caution... Not everything can be proven via a C program, unless it's a valid one. Many mistakenly take manifestations of undefined and implementation specific behavior for proofs.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, yes, you are right that one can't prove something by example.  But one can give examples for something that is correct.  For proof, one would look at the standard.  For example, the version I have says: *The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.*

Answer (score 0):

```
malloc(sizeof(*struct1))
```

allocates amount of memory equal to the size of the structure, depending upon the number of structure variables you have declared. Sizeof is used to return the size of  struct1, which is found during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. Declare the structure first,

```
typedef struct {

int a;
int b;
int c;

}MyStruct;
```

Then before allocating memory, initialize one structure variable and allocate memory as given,

```
MyStruct test;

printf("~~~~~ sizeofStruct: %ld", sizeof(test));

MyStruct *myAlloc = (MyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(test));

printf("~~~~~ sizeofmyAlloc: %ld", sizeof(*myAlloc));
```

Cheers !