# How to pass a struct member as a reference in a function?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

```c
#include<stdio.h> 
typedef struct { int i; float f; }num;
    
void func (int *);
    
int main() {
    num *ex; func(&ex->i);
    printf("Number = %d",ex->i);
}
    
void func(int *num) {
    *num = 4;
}
```

Why is a segmentation fault happening with this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does dynamically allocating a struct in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650858/how-does-dynamically-allocating-a-struct-in-c-work)

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't with passing the argument to `func`. `ex` is an uninitialized pointer to a `num` struct. You could allocate it explicitly (just don't forget to free it when you're done with it):

```
num* ex = malloc(sizeof(num));
```

Comment: Or, just do `num ex[1]`.  Or `num ex; func(&ex.i);`